# I need help converting text file to xml in Java

Tags: java, xml

I need help converting a text file to an xml file.

This is how I want the converted text file to look like:

```
   <ItemBonusDefinition>
        <id>88</id>
        <bonuses>
            <short>1</short>
            <short>1</short>
            <short>1</short>
        </bonuses>
    </ItemBonusDefinition>
    <ItemBonusDefinition>
        <id>89</id>
        <bonuses>
            <short>1</short>
            <short>1</short>
            <short>1</short>
        </bonuses>
    </ItemBonusDefinition>
```

This is what the text file looks like:

```
88
1.0
1.0
1.0
89
1.0
1.0
1.0
```

This is my code:

```
package com.test.tools;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXTransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.TransformerHandler;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.dom4j.Element;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import com.arlania.signlink;

public class ToXML {

    BufferedReader in;
    StreamResult out;
    TransformerHandler th;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new ToXML().begin();
    }

    public void begin() {
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(signlink.getCacheDirectory()+"items2.txt"));
            out = new StreamResult(signlink.getCacheDirectory()+"items4.xml");
            openXml();
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                process(str);
            }
            in.close();
            closeXml();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void openXml() throws ParserConfigurationException, TransformerConfigurationException, SAXException {

        SAXTransformerFactory tf = (SAXTransformerFactory) SAXTransformerFactory.newInstance();
        th = tf.newTransformerHandler();

        // pretty XML output
        Transformer serializer = th.getTransformer();
        serializer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
        serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

        th.setResult(out);
        th.startDocument();
        th.startElement(null, null, "list", null);
        th.startElement(null, null, "ItemBonusDefinition", null);
    }

    /**
     * Lists all the ints in <id> and the double in <short>. id are item id's and short is the bonus for the item id's
     * @param s
     * @throws SAXException
     */
    public void process(String s) throws SAXException {
        if (isInteger(s)) {
            th.startElement(null, null, "id", null);
            th.characters(s.toCharArray(), 0, s.length());
            th.endElement(null, null, "id");
        } else if (isDouble(s)) {
            th.startElement(null, null, "short", null);
            th.characters(s.toCharArray(), 0, s.length());
            th.endElement(null, null, "short");
        }
    }

    public void closeXml() throws SAXException {
        th.endElement(null, null, "ItemBonusDefinition");
        th.endElement(null, null, "list");
        th.endDocument();
    }

    public boolean isDouble( String str ){
        try{
            Double.parseDouble( str );
            return true;
        }
        catch( Exception e ){
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean isInteger(Object object) {
        if(object instanceof Integer) {
            return true;
        } else {
            String string = object.toString();

            try {
                Integer.parseInt(string);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                return false;
            }   
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

The code outputs this:

```
<ItemBonusDefinition>
        <id>88</id>
        <short>1.0</short>
        <short>1.0</short>
        <short>1.0</short>
        <id>89</id>
        <short>1.0</short>
        <short>1.0</short>
        <short>1.0</short>
```

I need help adding the `<bonuses>` correctly as in the first example and `<ItemBonusDefinition>` aswell. It must look EXACTLY as in the first example. I will appreciate any help I can get :)

Comment: Try to use dom4j instead of javax. And the converted text you want is an invalid xml format because it doesn't have a root element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this dom4j code, it can generate xml file you want.

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.dom4j.Document;
import org.dom4j.DocumentHelper;
import org.dom4j.Element;
import org.dom4j.io.OutputFormat;
import org.dom4j.io.XMLWriter;

public class Convert {

    private static final int LINES_PER_ELEMENT = 4;
    private static final int COUNT_OF_ELEMENTS = 2;
    private static final int ID_INDEX = 0;

    public static List<String> getFile() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        File file = new File("text");
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            br = new BufferedReader(reader);
            String line = null;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                list.add(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static Document getXml(List<String> lines) {
        Element root = DocumentHelper.createElement("root");
        Document document = DocumentHelper.createDocument(root);
        String[][] strArr = new String[COUNT_OF_ELEMENTS][LINES_PER_ELEMENT];
        for(int i = 0;i < COUNT_OF_ELEMENTS;i++) {
            for(int j = 0;j < LINES_PER_ELEMENT;j++) {
                strArr[i][j] = lines.get((i + 1) * (j + 1) - 1);
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0;i < COUNT_OF_ELEMENTS;i++) {
            Element itemBonusDefinition = root.addElement("ItemBonusDefinition");
            String[] elemValues = strArr[i];
            Element id = itemBonusDefinition.addElement("id");
            Element bonus = itemBonusDefinition.addElement("bonus");
            for(int j = 0;j < elemValues.length;j++) {
                if(j == ID_INDEX) {
                    id.setText(elemValues[j]);
                } else {
                    Element shorT = bonus.addElement("short");
                    shorT.setText(elemValues[j]);
                }
            }
        }
        return document;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<String> lines = getFile();
        Document document = getXml(lines);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\test11.xml");
        Writer wr = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
        OutputFormat format = OutputFormat.createPrettyPrint();
        XMLWriter writer = new XMLWriter(wr,format);
        writer.write(document);
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

The result is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <root>
   <ItemBonusDefinition>
     <id>88</id>
     <bonus>
       <short>1.0</short>
       <short>1.0</short>
       <short>1.0</short>
     </bonus>
   </ItemBonusDefinition>
   <ItemBonusDefinition>
     <id>1.0</id>
     <bonus>
       <short>1.0</short>
       <short>1.0</short>
       <short>1.0</short>
     </bonus>
   </ItemBonusDefinition>
 </root>
```

Comment: You are a legend, thank you so much for the help! :)

Comment: Could you help me with 1 more thing? I want only every value which is double to be added into <short>.

Comment: Tyr to make `shorT.setText(elemValues[j]);` be `shorT.setText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(elemValues[j]) * 2));`